# Creating Unity games for older versions of Android?

Tags: unity, android

[image: Android]

In the Unity editor, the lowest available Android version for debugging is Android 2.3.1 In my case, I have a phone running an older version of Android and I intend to publish my game to a wide audience. With the lowest version being 2.3.1, I see a problem publishing my games to older smartphones which still occupy a considerable size of the market share. My question is: Is there a way to publish my game to older versions of Android? Or is it impossible?

Comment: geez 2.3.1 came out in 2010 and that's not old enough? damn yo; I'm not sure Unity even built to Android before then.

Comment: Aight. I did not formulate my question very well. What I meant is that devices with Android 2.3.1 or less still represents a relatively large number of smartphones, especially in developing countries.

Comment: There's a reason I wrote a comment and not an answer. I understood your question perfectly well.

Comment: Pre gingerbread occupies 0.2% of the market according to Google; http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform and it was quite a big change between froyo and gingerbread so it's painful to go pre gingerbread. Personally even supporting gingerbread (3.8%) is only worth it if it doesn't compromise your design

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264936/creating-unity-games-for-older-versions-of-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [Bart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488657/bart) from [the same question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264936/creating-unity-games-for-older-versions-of-android):

> Versions later than Unity 4.2.x don't support Android versions earlier than 2.3.x. So if your project relies on functionality only present in 4.3.x and higher, you're out of luck.
>
> Otherwise you can still download a 4.2.x or earlier version of Unity and create your builds with that.